# Problem with function "from_file()" at z3py

Tags: z3, solver, z3py

Let's assume that we have the following files:

- func.smt

```
    (declare-datatypes (T) ((AVL leafA (nodeA (val T) (alt Int) (izq AVL) (der AVL)))))
```

- espec.smt

```
     (declare-const t (AVL  Int))
```

And the following code:

```
    from z3 import *

    s = Solver()

    s.from_file("func.smt")
    s.from_file("espec.smt")
```

When instruction "s.from_file("espec.smt")" is executed, z3 throws the next exception:

```
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: b'(error "line 1 column 18: unknown sort \'AVL\'")\n'
```

It seems that the Solver "s" doesn't save the information of datatypes (and functions too). That is why he throws the exception (I guess).

The following code is a way to solve it:

```
    s = Solver()

    file = open("func.smt", "r")
    func = file.read()
    file.close()

    file = open("espec.smt", "r")
    espec = file.read()
    file.close()

    s.from_string(func + espec)
```

But this way it's not efficient.

Is there another more efficient way to solve this and make z3 save datatypes and functions for future asserts and declarations?

**Edit:**

In my real case for example, the file "func.smt" has a total of 54 declarations between functions and datatypes (some quite complex). The "spec.smt" file has few declarations and asserts. And finally I have a file in which there are many asserts which I have to read little by little and generate a model.

That is, imagine that I have 600 lines of asserts, and I read from 10 to 10, so every 10 lines I generate a model. That is, if we assume that those asserts that I have read are stored in a variable called "aux", every time I want to get a new model, I will have to do "s.from_string (func + spec + aux)" 60 times in total, and I don't know if that could be made more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separately reading the files and loading to solver is your best bet, as you found out.

Unless efficiency is of paramount importance, I would not worry about trying to optimize this any further. For any reasonable problem, your solver time will dominate any time spent in loading the assertions from a few (or a few thousand!) files. Do you have a use case that really requires this part to be significantly faster?

Comment: I have edited my post with a real use case that seems quite large and can be slow in this way.

Comment: I very much doubt that’ll be a concern. Why don’t you do some profiling to see how long reading+loading takes as compared to solving. Without actual performance numbers you’ll most likely be going after the wrong thing to optimize. Note that someone has to read all those files: whether it’s you or z3, the cost of IO will be there regardless. Use a mutable string to concatenate if necessary. It won’t get any faster than that.